# Celery task / worker assignment logic

Tags: python, python-3.x, celery, celery-task

Hello stackoverflow people!

I would like to discuss and see what's the better approach to my problem.

I have an application that send files to clients using multiple protocols (FTP(S), SFTP, S3, EMail).

There's a celery task per directory. A directory can be send to multiple clients and can be send to multiple destinations. e.g. dir1 -> client1 -> FTP and EMail (2 tasks, fine to run in parallel), dir2 -> client1 AND client2 -> same FTP hostname, different remote directories (2 tasks, not fine to run in parallel).

This is working fine, however I'm causing client network congestion sometimes, due to multiple connections from multiple workers to the same destination, some clients don't know (or want to implement) QOS.

I would like to have a logic that don't allow tasks connecting to the same protocol or hostname running at the same time. Per example, a directory that is being send to 2 x S3 buckets, should run once, after it finished the second will start. Or two different directories that is being send to the same FTP server.

My initial idea is to implement a celery_worker queue remote control. One queue for each account, protocol. And setup workers with concurrency 1 listening on the queues.

Wondering if any of you had a similar challenge and how did you workaround it.

Comment: So to understand you can parallelize sending files to same client via different protocols, however cannot parallelize sending to muliple clients via the same protocol, right ?

Comment: protocols can be parallelized, I can't parallelize files being sent to the same server.

Answer (score 1):

Your proposed solution is rather brittle (you really shouldn't rely on celery concurrency settings to control/prevent concurrent execution) and will probably not solve all the potential race conditions (for example if taskA and taskB are on different queues but need to access a resource that doesn't support concurrent access).

There are quite a couple recipes (from rather informal advises to full-blown libs like celery-once) to prevent concurrent execution of one given task. They don't directly solve your own problem but basically the principle is the same: have some shared lock mechanism that the tasks communicate with - try to acquire the lock, only run once they get it, and of course release it. If you're using Redis as result backend, it's rather low read/write cost and it's 'expire' feature can be really helpful, but you can also just use your SQL database.